# How to lookup Azure drive type?

Tags: azure-storage

When creating/resizing OS and Data drives Azure programmatically picks a drive type for you. E.g. standard SSD:

- e4
- e10
- e15
- or magnetic s6, s20, ...

Those show up in the cost analysis the next day. E.g. [image]

How to look up the drive type, without waiting 24 hours to see what you payed for?

**UPDATE: March 23, here are all the disks I created - I only have two disks now**
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say you are creating them programmatically are you referring to the API, PowerShell, or the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining managed disks you choose the type (Premium SSD, Standard SSD, and Standard HDD) and size.  The type determines the class of storage (P, E, S) and then the size allocation sets the description.  With that in mind, your configuration determines the value that will be used.  For example, S10 = Standard SSD 128 Gb

Here is a reference:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/

Unfortunately, it is not explicitly displayed in the disk properties so it looks like the description is assigned as part of the reporting process as it evaluates the composite values.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. I added  all the disks. I edited in the details into my question as "UPDATE: March 23"

Lets see what comes out in the billing..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. If we put the Disks type such as P30, E, S in Disks configuration under Disks tab for the VM, would it satisfy your requirement? You should be able to see disk properties of a particular VM as soon as you have provisioned a VM.

[image: Disk type]

Comment: Yes. That would resolve the confusion and save a lot of time.